# Why does GHC run version 7.10.3 instead of 8.6.2?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am new to Haskell (as in, have yet to write a single line of Haskell code). I recently downloaded GHC version 8.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 via the ppa:hvr/ghc.  However, when I run

`$ ghc --version`

I get

`The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3`

I can run version 8.6.2 using the command

`$ /opt/ghc/bin/ghc-8.6.2 --version`

so I assume this is normal behaviour. However, I don't understand why it automatically runs version 7.10.3. Additionally, is there a way I can change it so that the `ghc` command will automatically run the latest version installed?

I did try searching for answers previously, but was unable to find any. Any explanations / help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will run whichever comes first in your `$PATH`. Adjust your `$PATH`, so that /opt/ghc/bin comes first or uninstall the other GHC.

Comment: Do you have `/opt/ghc/bin/:` directory listed in the `$PATH` variable..? If not you have an earlier version of GHC already installed in one of the directories listed under `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Run `which -a ghc`; you should get back multiple paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about ghc, system administration, or both.

GHC ships as individual versions of the compiler - just as gcc or any other compiler I can think of.  If you run the ghc 8.6.2 binary then it will report version 8.6.2.  If you run some unknown ghc and ask it for the version, as you did with just `$ ghc --version`, then you'll see the results from the first ghc binary in the path.  You can even find out which binary using `which ghc` and `ls -l $(which ghc)`.

So you seem to have multiple GHC binaries installed.  Again, this is something to do with your administration of this system.  I suggest you:

1. Go through and remove any previously installed GHC binaries from apt etc
2. Set a path to include the HVR PPA ghc you just installed.  For example, edit `$HOME/.bashrc` if you use bash and add `PATH=/opt/ghc/bin:$PATH` to the end of the file.